# unable to execute a store procedure getting error

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Can any one help me to execute the below procedure in PL/SQL. I am getting error as

```
declare
TYPE c_charge_code_arra IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
 myarray c_charge_code_arra;
 out_val number := 12;
begin
myarray(0) := 'hg';
 BRANCH_BKK.air_pkg.airinvoice_pd('01','13070410012','4610032','A','IN','bkkrp_bkk','Asia/Bangkok','56YUSEN',null,myarray,null,'B',out_val); 
end;
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 7, column 2:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'AIRINVOICE_PD'
ORA-06550: line 7, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Below is the package declaration. When I try to execute the below procedure I get the above error. Thanks in Advance

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BRANCH_BKK.air_pkg AS

TYPE c_charge_code_arra IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20) INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;


PROCEDURE airinvoice_pd (in_company IN varchar2,
                    in_file_no    IN varchar2,
                    c_reference    IN varchar2,
                    in_run_option    IN varchar2,
                    in_invoice_type    IN varchar2,
                    in_user        IN varchar2,
                    c_time_zone in varchar2,
                    in_payor_code IN varchar2,
                    in_payor_reference IN varchar2,
                    i_charge_code IN c_charge_code_arra,
                    in_invoice_number IN varchar2,
                    in_invoice_against IN varchar2,
                    out_message OUT varchar2);
```

Comment: you don't even tell use what the error is.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete Question. I have edited the question. Can you please help me out

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your declaration of myarray.  You are attempting to re-declare the table type in the calling script, when instead, you need to declare the variable of the table type defined in the package spec:

```
DECLARE
   myarray   BRANCH_BKK.air_pkg.c_charge_code_arra;
   out_val   NUMBER                     := 12;
BEGIN
   myarray (0) := 'hg';
   BRANCH_BKK.air_pkg.airinvoice_pd ('01',
                          '13070410012',
                          '4610032',
                          'A',
                          'IN',
                          'bkkrp_bkk',
                          'Asia/Bangkok',
                          '56YUSEN',
                          NULL,
                          myarray,
                          NULL,
                          'B',
                          out_val
                         );
END;
```